# Is the DC on the Linguist Feat too low?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

I am talking specifically about the DC to create a cipher. As written the DC is INT+Proficency. This means that as a level 14 wizard with a 20 INT, I can create a cipher with a DC of 10. This seems to be quite low to me?

Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> DC equal to your Intelligence score + your proficiency bonus

This uses your intelligence *score*, not your intelligence *modifier*.  Therefore the DC is 25 (20 Int + 5 Proficiency modifier).

Answer (score 23):

You are reading INT+Proficiency as meaning INT Modifier+Proficiency.

Add the full intelligence score, so a level 14 wizard with a 20 Int, sets the DC of their ciphers as 25.